# Wordpress + Paypal Change user role on Paypal Payment

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

am developping a gaming clan website, and i got a simple paypal form where ppl can choose how much they want to donate, i can send **any user info** to paypal, but i wanted to know how to use the **Paypal IPN** to **listen when donation has been made** and change that **user role to 'Donator'**  `(On php obviusly..)`

*-Eg.. Paypal Form > Payment > Success > User Role = 'Donator'.*

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start [with this](https://packagist.org/packages/mike182uk/paypal-ipn-listener).  You can use that and build it into a WP plugin that'll handle what you're trying to do pretty easily.